# Rest datasource in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying since six hours to add the rest plugin, found here: [CakePHP-Rest-Datasource](https://github.com/nodesagency/CakePHP-Rest-Datasource)

The problem is that it has many error messages. Now after trying many options  I have the following error message :

`Declaration of Resource::query() should be compatible with DboSource::query()`

Someone has an idea?

Comment: You should show us your related code so we can give more detailed input.

Comment: I followed exactly the git documentation. This error message came from the class datasource that I pulled

Comment: when i see versions, not sure that plugin is validate

Answer (score 2):

[This has been asked a few thousand times before.](https://www.google.de/search?q=php%20Declaration%20of%20should%20be%20compatible%20with) Try searching for error messages if you don't know what they mean. But this one is very clear IMHO.

This is a php5 strict error message telling you that the signature of the methods don't match. **Make them match.** Create a bug type ticket for the plugin or fix it yourself and create a pull request.

The plugin hasn't been updated for over 2 years and doesn't have *any* tests. I would not recommend to use it.

Comment: is there any other validated rest api plugin?

Comment: I don't know. Use Google and check if one you find has tests and run them in your 2.6 environment? Or simply fix it.